# Obter diferença entre horas Definida/Atual

Tags: javascript, node.js

Gostaria de obter quantas horas se passou, de uma determinada data, para a data atual. Por exemplo:

```
day = "Thu May 19 2016 05:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)";
today = "tue May 23 2016 09:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)";
```

Variável `day` possui a data inicial, a partir dessa data gostaria de começar a contar as horas. E a variável `today` possui a data atual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resposta simplista talvez, mas se só queres as horas de diferênça podes fazer :

```
var horas = Math.abs(data_A - data_B) / 36e5;
```

- `Math.abs` para dar um numero positivo e ser assim indiferente a ordem das datas
- `/ 36e5` porque esse valor é o mesmo que 3600000 que é 60 segundos x 60 minutos x 1000 milisegundos. Isto porque datas em javascript são em milisegundos.

### Exemplo:

```js
var day = "Thu May 19 2016 05:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)";
var today = "tue May 23 2016 09:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)";

var horas = Math.abs(new Date(day) - new Date(today)) / 36e5;
alert(horas); // 100
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
day = new Date("Thu May 19 2016 05:00:00 GMT-0300");
today = new Date("tue May 23 2016 09:00:00 GMT-0300");

document.write(diferencaDias(day,today));

function diferencaDias(data1, data2){
    var dif =
        Date.UTC(data1.getYear(),data1.getMonth(),data1.getDate(),0,0,0)
      - Date.UTC(data2.getYear(),data2.getMonth(),data2.getDate(),0,0,0);
      dif=Math.abs((dif / 1000 / 60 / 60));
      difH=Math.abs(today.getHours()-day.getHours());
      difM=Math.abs(today.getMinutes()-day.getMinutes());
      difS=Math.abs(today.getSeconds()-day.getSeconds());
    return ((dif+difH)+"Horas   "+difM+"Minutos    "+difS+"Segundos");
}
```

Comment: Dessa forma, ele pega os dias, não as horas certo ? Pq no exemplo que eu coloquei, o resultado é 3 dias e 20hs, então 92hs

Comment: +1 pelo uso de abs para garantir que não haverá diferença "negativa" de tempo. Agora, o Jonathan está certo... remover a divisão por 24 no final do código fará com que ele retorne as horas, como a pergunta pede.

Comment: Já alterei e está a funcionar, dá a diferença em horas, minutos e segundos.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) e fazer algo parecido com isso:

```js
var today  = moment("Tue May 23 2016 09:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)");
var day = moment("Thu May 19 2016 05:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)");

var duracao = moment.duration(today.diff(day));
var horas = duracao.asHours();
console.log(horas)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Diz que o objeto `today` não possui o método diff. Sabe me dizer pq?

Comment: Você instalou a biblioteca?

Comment: Sim. Mas o problema é no objeto `today`, e não na parte do `moment`. Ai acho que não interfere mesmo se eu não tivesse instalado.

Comment: Interfere pois o método `diff` é parte do `moment`. De uma analisada no código, talvez vc esteja esquecendo de algo.

Comment: Exemplo funcionando no jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sinkz/koznnzvo/2/